# How do I add a different background color past the end of a page?

Tags: css, background-color

**Basic Premise:** I'm on MacOS, and like many mobile platforms built around a touchscreen or touchpad, the scrolling is, for lack of a better description, "stretchy". That is to say, if you scroll to the beginning or end of a page, you can scroll past it somewhat with a stretchy feel to it. (Sorry if there is some official terminology I'm missing.)

**What I Want:** I have designed a page with a white background, but the footer at the bottom of the page is black. I know it is a small detail, but I think it would look very nice if the area past the bottom of the page had a black background color to match the footer.

**Question:** Is there any way to achieve this? Specifically, can I have the color of the background past the bottom of my page be different from the background for the rest of the page?

Comment: You can always create another div around everything and give both the div and the body a background color and padding. Is this what you meant?

Comment: It's called "overscroll" and theoretically, [CSS has a way of making it stop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overscroll-behavior).

Comment: Although, you should be aware that overscroll isn't supported on IOS Safari

Comment: @askingforafriend Currently. I linked to MDN precisely so that the OP (and later visitors) could view the supported browser list at the bottom of the page, which may change over time.

Answer (score 1):

You can style the background color of the HTML, see this link as well: https://peter.coffee/htmls-background-color.

The relevant (css) part looks like this:

```
html {
  background-color: $header-footer-color;
}

body {
  background-color: $maybe-white;
}
```

If you have a different color for the header, and a different one for the footer you could use a gradient; source: https://gist.github.com/peterramsing/d3ba8502730471691f73361f0490a185#gistcomment-3512344

Comment: Tried this. Looks like a gradient still scrolls with the page when you overscroll past either end, so this solution doesn't work. Also, I do have a different color for my header and footer, so a plain background color that matches my header is so far the best I can do.

Comment: Indeed, linear-gradient not working on iOS, just background color.

Comment: It's 2023 and gradient backgrounds for html still don't work on iOS...